# Knockout.js - Sort observable array by property of another observable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, knockout.js

Sorry if the title isn't very descriptive! I am trying to reorder an observable array based on the order of another observable array. For example

```
self.tagging_fields = ko.observableArray(['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3'])

function Tag(data){
    var self = this;
    self.field_name = ko.observable(data.field_name);

}

var example_tags = [
    new Tag({field_name : "field_3"}),
    new Tag({field_name : "field_2"}),
    new Tag({field_name : "field_1"})
]

self.tags = ko.observableArray(example_tags);

//This is what I want to achieve
var after_sorting = [
    { field_name : "field_1" },
    { field_name : "field_2" },
    { field_name : "field_3" }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is sort the order of the tag objects by field_name within self.tags based on the order they appear within self.tagging_fields. Could anyone help me out to write a custom sort function for this operation

Update:

I have managed to achieve what I want within the output foreach

I've worked around it by doing a comparison within the output foreach

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: $root.tagging_fields, as : 'tagging_field' }">
     <div data-bind="foreach: { data : line.tags, as : 'tag' }">
          <div data-bind="if: tag.field_name() === tagging_field">
              <span data-bind="text: tag.field_name"></span>
              <input data-bind="value: tag.value"/><br/>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>`
```

I know it's probably not the best way but it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like (untested):

```
self.tags.sort(function(left, right) { 
    var leftIndex = self.tagging_fields.indexOf(left);
    var rightIndex = self.tagging_fields.indexOf(right);
    return leftIndex  == rightIndex 
        ? 0 : (leftIndex  < rightIndex  ? -1 : 1) 
});
```

See [doc here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#pop-push-shift-unshift-reverse-sort-splice).

Comment: I'm trying to compare it against the values in self.tagging_fields so I think I need to loop within this too:

`ko.utils.arrayForEach(root.tagging_fields(), function(item) {}`

But this is where I get lost trying to do the comparison

Comment: Oh you mean you want to keep the order but you might have different tags in `self.tags` and in `self.tagging_fields`, and you want to keep the order from `self.tagging_fields` that might not be alphabetical?

Comment: Yes that right, I'm trying to reorder the Tag objects within self.tags based on the order of self.tagging_fields